# name can only contain URL-friendly characters NPM Install @@angular/platform-browser

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have a project and I'm trying to give npm install, but it is giving the following error:

`npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME npm ERR! Invalid package name "@@angular/platform-browser": name can only contain URL-friendly character`

I tried uninstalling nodejs and npm, deleted node_modules,npm cache clean and nothing is working.Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json rename the dependency `@@angular/platform-browser` to `@angular/platform-browser`

Comment: The project which I'm working on package.json folder seems to be correct. There is no '@@' in package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

The scoped packages usually contain @ at the beginning. It is @angular/platform-browser, instead of @@angular/platform-browser.

Just change above in package.json and npm install. It should work.

Comment: The project which I'm working on package.json folder seems to be correct. There is no '@@' in package.json file.